# How to create multiline backBarButtonItem in UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar

I want to create multiline BackBarButtonItem. right now my back button display like this,

[image]

but i want to display it like this, color does not matter,

[image]

How can I do that? And this is my default back button which added while i am pushing my childviewcontroller thru my parentviewcontroller so i dont want to remove it.

Comment: You may be able to use an image... I don't believe that `UIBarButtonItem` supports multiline text.

Comment: @SimonM thanx for reply, thats what i have in mind. but want to refer it thru expert like you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using custom image,UILabel(MSLabel),UIButton.

[MSLabel](https://github.com/LemonCake/MSLabel) is used to change space between two line of UILabel. Because UILabel Does not provide any property to do that.

After you add MSLabel in your project use this code. Recommend size for `backbtn.png` is  48*30.

```
#import "MSLabel.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set the custom back button
    UIImage *buttonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"backbtn.png"]
                            resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 13, 0, 5)];



    //create the button and assign the image
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    MSLabel *lbl = [[MSLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 4, 65, 28)];
    lbl.text = @"Account Summary";
    lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    //lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0];
    lbl.numberOfLines = 0;

    lbl.lineHeight = 12;
    lbl.verticalAlignment = MSLabelVerticalAlignmentMiddle;
    lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];

    [button addSubview:lbl];

    //set the frame of the button to the size of the image (see note below)
     button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, buttonImage.size.height);

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    //create a UIBarButtonItem with the button as a custom view
    UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;

}

-(void)back {
    NSLog(@"Dilip Back To ParentViewController");
    // Tell the controller to go back
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Outcome will display like this, Use your image for better result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should use custom button and use background image on this button.Because i think it may not be possible.See for custom button

```
    UIButton *backBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f,6.5f,60.0f,30.0f)];
    [backBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"accountSummary"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"accountSummary"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [backBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(accountSummaryBtnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *leftButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backBtn];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:leftButton];


- (void)accountSummaryBtnPressed:(id)sender
{
    //--------- do stuff for account summary 
}
```

Comment: Thanx for reply, is put image is batter than puting button?

Comment: button will be better and set image on button. Because you can't call action method on UIImageView.

Comment: If there is no localization support, then this method should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

What i believe you can Create CustomView with ImageView And Transparent label with `numberOflines` more than two or whatever you want to restrict it to , then replace the navigation back button with That Barbutton initiated with CustomVIew, That Can Solve your problem,, Hope fully